# Django installation picking up wrong path names for migrate after project was copied

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have tried to create a new Django project on my Mac by making a copy of an existing working Django project.

I have tried to remove references to the old project paths from the new project but when doing a migrate or createsuperuser I get an error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: invalid connection option "init_command"
```

Both projects use a virtual environment called myvenv. The original project used the MySQL database. The new one uses Postgresql which has been installed in the virtual environment.

The trace history for the error shows that some of the paths show the correct path name of `yhistory-server` and some show the path name for the old project from which the new project was copied: `veeuserver`. I have been through all my code but cannot see where it is picking up the veeuserver path name from.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 52, in execute
return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 86, in handle
default_username = get_default_username()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 189, in get_default_username
auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 381, in get
num = len(clone)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 240, in __len__
self._fetch_all()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
results = compiler.execute_sql()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 846, in execute_sql
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 175, in get_new_connection
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/VeeUServer/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: invalid connection option "init_command"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I experienced the same issue when moving a site from MySQL to Postgres. The key lies in the settings.py file, particularly where you specify the database option. In MySQL, it looked like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
    },
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': password,
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'POST': '',
    }
}
```

In order to make it work with Postgres, I had to change the engine to 'django.db.backends.postgresql', delete the OPTIONS and POST, and add PORT: '5432'. It now looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': password,
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still trying to use a postgres database. You should update the `DATABASES` setting to use django's mysql backend, and you may need to remove all of your migrations as well. After you've removed the migrations and change the `DATABASES` settings, you should be able to `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py makemigrations` then finally `createsupersuser`.

Comment: The problem is with the new project which needs to use postgre not mysql.

Comment: Sorry- misread the text. Have you changed the DATABASES setting?

Comment: How should the database settings be changed?

Comment: Set  ENGINE to use 'django.db.backends.mysql' instead of postgresql. You will also have to modify the other database settings to match the new database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/

Comment: The new project uses a postgresql database so surely setting the engine to mysql wont work?

Comment: Right, @denvaar means to use 'django.db.backends.postgresql'